# How to support both PostgreSQL and SQL Server in a Node.JS application?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, node.js, orm

I'm currently developing a Node.js app that needs to be able to switch between PostgreSQL and SQL Server databases. Both databases have identical tables and the operations will also be identical (basic CRUD, nothing fancy).

I've done research, and know that there are enough libraries around to access both databases.

Ideally I'd like to use a ORM and just let that handle the differences. However, I can't seem to find an ORM framework that does both. In fact, I can't locate any ORM that supports SQL Server, while almost all support Postgres.

So my question: is there an ORM that supports both? And if there isn't, are there other abstraction tools/frameworks around that will make my developer life easier?

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but I ended up diving into JugglingDB (https://github.com/1602/jugglingdb/) It has a fairly simple way of integrating new databases. I haven't implemented the full adapter, so right now it's not ready for general usage, but I hope to some day complete it and donate it to the project (client is fine with it).

Answer (score 1):

There is a certain amount of [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it) here, but if you are unable to find an ORM that supports both, your next best bet is to just use an [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) and ensure you're not using the ORM directly in your code, but through a wrapper. Then if / when you need support for SQL Server, you can create the implementation for the wrapper which will replace the PostgreSQL implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is YAGNI. I've got two different databases with the same tables. I need an app that can handle both (but not at the same time, this would be an option at startup). And I prefer to use an ORM layer because it reduces the time needed to code SQL and other boilerplate.

Comment: And you are correct, the adapter pattern is probably the way to go.